# For what culinary reason would a bread recipe choose skim milk?

Tags: bread, milk

Skim milk is specified for the whole wheat bread recipe list included with my new bread maker. Is there a particular culinary reason to specify skim milk not skim milk/whole milk? The other ingredients are whole wheat flour, self-raising flour, salt, sugar and yeast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skim milk contains less fat than whole milk. Fats limit the formation of gluten in bread dough to some extent, leading to a tighter, 'softer' crumb. As the milk is apparently the only source of water in your recipe, the recipe authors could have tried to limit the amount of fat.

That said, there is also a good chance the reason for skim milk is health-related.

Comment: I would think health related most likely - regular milk is about 2.5% - so a 250 ml cup contains about 6.25 ml of fats/oils, which is not enough to affect the crumb through fat content. Most bread recipes will contain about 30-50 ml of fat/oil for a 750 g loaf and you can vary this widely to get a softer crust and dough. However, the source of the fats/oils is a contentious issue - animal derived fats being seen as particularly bad health-wise by many people.

Comment: A factor might how small loaves are in Japan. We make double loaf and it is something like  only 10 cm by 7 cm

Comment: @user2617804 The size of a loaf is determined by the amount (and shape of) the dough you use, not by the ingredients.